# Single, double, or triple double quotes for Python’s raw string notation for regex?

Tags: python, regex

I wonder when to use which for Python’s raw string notation for regular expressions: single quotes, double quotes, or triple double quotes?

From https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

> When used with triple-quoted strings, this enables REs to be formatted more neatly:
>
> ```
> pat = re.compile(r"""
>  \s*                 # Skip leading whitespace
>  (?P<header>[^:]+)   # Header name
>  \s* :               # Whitespace, and a colon
>  (?P<value>.*?)      # The header's value -- *? used to
>                      # lose the following trailing whitespace
>  \s*$                # Trailing whitespace to end-of-line
> """, re.VERBOSE)
> ```

I replaced the triple double quotes, with double quotes, and with single quotes, but neither works.

The article, however, also uses single quotes, and double quotes in other examples:

```
r"\w+\s+\1"

r'(\b\w+)\s+\1'
```

I wonder why?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing specific to regex here. 1) Double and single quotes are equivalent. 2) Triple quotes are for multi-line string literals. Same goes for raw strings.

Comment: triple apostrophes and triple quotes are multiline string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The benefit of raw strings**

With raw strings you don't have to worry about backslashes inside the string as, in:

```
r"\d"
```

Without the `r`, the string would not reach the engine in the state you expect. You would have to escape the backslash.

**The benefit of triple quotes**

With triple quotes (as others have said) is that your strings can span multiple lines, as in:

```
r"""(?x)   # let's write this complex regex in free-space mode!
\d         # match a digit
$          # at the end of a line
"""
```

Comment: @JanneKarila Gosh, that's embarrassing, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

The triple quote example demonstrates verbose mode where whitespace is stripped from the regex and you can use the whitepace to increase readability. Strangely, the example fails to mention the other part about verbose: it ignores everything past the # to the end of line as a comment. Since triple quotes preserve the line breaks, regex sees multiple lines that have comments on the end of them.

```
>>> print (r"""
...  \s*                 # Skip leading whitespace
...  (?P<header>[^:]+)   # Header name
...  \s* :               # Whitespace, and a colon
... ...
... """)

 \s*                 # Skip leading whitespace
 (?P<header>[^:]+)   # Header name
 \s* :               # Whitespace, and a colon
...

>>>
```

If you just used a bunch of single quotes to concatenate the strings, it only sees one line with a very long comment.

```
>>> print (
... r" \s*                 # Skip leading whitespace"
... r" (?P<header>[^:]+)   # Header name"
... r" \s* :               # Whitespace, and a colon"
... r"...")
 \s*                 # Skip leading whitespace (?P<header>[^:]+)   # Header name \s* :               # Whitespace, and a colon...
>>>
```

You could add \n to the end of each string to get back to a multiline string.

As for single verses double quotes, its all just personal preference and doesn't matter to python or the regex. If the quoted string contains ", then ' is convenient for quoting, and vice-a-versa, that's it.